# Binding Xamarin XAML to code behind properties (ListView)

Tags: xamarin, data-binding, properties, code-behind

I want to bind my code-behind property, which is a list, to a XAML ListView. However, my ListView is never populated and I have no idea why.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="BLEPl.EvaluationPage"
             Title="Evaluation">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Padding="0,20,0,20">      
            <ListView HasUnevenRows="True" IsVisible="True" x:Name="TableLayout" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SensorValues}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid>
                                <Label Style="{StaticResource TitleLabel}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="Zeitstempel: " />
                                <Label Style="{StaticResource DataLabel}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding TimeStamp}" />

                                <Label Style="{StaticResource TitleLabel}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="Wert: " />
                                <Label Style="{StaticResource DataLabel}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Value}" />

                                <Label Style="{StaticResource TitleLabel}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="Sensor: " />
                                <Label Style="{StaticResource DataLabel}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Sensor.Name}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>

[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class EvaluationPage : ContentPage
{
    private ObservableCollection<SensorValue> SensorValues = new ObservableCollection<SensorValue>();

    public EvaluationPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        using (var context = new BlepContext(true))
        {
            var repo = new BLEPRepository(context);
            SensorValues = new ObservableCollection<SensorValue>(repo.GetAllSensorValues());
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, my ListView doesn't contain any items. I do not get errors and my app compiles fine. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: a) you can only bind to public properties, and b) you don't appear to be setting your BindingContext

Comment: I am sorry, I already made my property public but I seemed to have Ctrl-Z too far. What do you mean by your second statement? I have tried setting it like this: `BindingContext="{x:Reference this}` in the ListView XAML, but I got an error: `Can not find the object referenced by 'this'`

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListView HasUnevenRows="True" IsVisible="True" x:Name="TableLayout" ItemsSource="{Binding SensorValues}">
```

you can only bind to public properties, and you need to set a BindingContext for the page

```
// needs to be a PUBLIC PROPERTY
public ObservableCollection<SensorValue> SensorValues { get; set; }

public EvaluationPage ()
{
    InitializeComponent ();

    // set the BindingContext
    this.BindingContext = this;

    using (var context = new BlepContext(true))
    {
        var repo = new BLEPRepository(context);
        SensorValues = new ObservableCollection<SensorValue>(repo.GetAllSensorValues());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to put `this.BindingContext = this;` in XAML?

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/69279/how-to-set-bindingcontext-to-a-page-itself